# SwiftUI: Alignment not applied

Tags: swiftui

I have a small example that U do not understand:
Why is the alignment of my ZStack not applied to all of it's children? The TopView stays on top but I would expect, that every child would be on bottom right:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            VStack {
                TopView()
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("A new layer")
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct TopView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                Text("SwiftUI")
                Text("Layout")
            }
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "star")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all the views are in the middle of area they need. Even you're using `VStack` it will be in the middle of the screen and be with height of two `Text` (as in your example).
`ZStack` has the same behavior - it will be as small as possible and right in the center of safe area.

`Spacer` just under `TopView` tries to take all the free space. Just as `Spacer` between star and texts.
So `VStack` in your `ZStack` technically is on `.bottomTrailing`, but takes all the free space. Just try to remove or change position of `Spacer`'s:

[image]